# Ray collision fails with THREE.Sprite

Tags: three.js, raycasting

I'm using projector and raycaster to intersect a Three.Sprite object, however, I could get the object even if I touch outside of the image bounding. So, I deep into the three.js file, and I found a piece of source:

```
var intersectObject = function ( object, raycaster, intersects ) {  
if ( object instanceof THREE.Sprite ) {  
   matrixPosition.getPositionFromMatrix( object.matrixWorld ); 
var distance = raycaster.ray.distanceToPoint( matrixPosition );
if ( distance > object.scale.x ) {
    return intersects;
} 
intersects.push( { 
    distance: distance, 
    point: object.position, 
    face: null, 
    object: object 
});
```

I couldn't understand `if ( distance > object.scale.x )`, I think it's the problem I meet. I am a newbie with Threejs. Does I  go worng? Thanks for any help!!

Comment: `distance` is the perpendicular distance from the sprite's world position to the line defined by the ray. That value should be compared to `0.5 * object.scale.x`, I think. And even so, it is just an approximation, since `scale.y` may be a different value. Also, it does not appear to check if the sprite is behind the ray. So you are correct, it appears there are problems with the code.

Comment: I agree. Hopefully this problem be fixed soon.